# Forward engineering in mysql work bench not working

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have created a EER diagram in mysql work bench but I am not able to forward engineer the diagram into a db and tables based on the schema and diagram I have created. Nothing happens when I select the forward engineer menu.

Reverse engineering works though. I am sitting on a mac os Sierra machine.

Thanks

Comment: This is legit question and happens for me, too.

Comment: This happened to me first on Yosemite, then I upgraded to Sierra. Same issue. running v 6.3.9 build 10690321 CE 64 bit.

Comment: That's a regression and must be fixed. Please file a bug report at http://bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: i suppose there's no fix for it yet? this works fine under my Windows VM, just not Mac.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward engineer is doing nothing in the MySQL Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43067054/forward-engineer-is-doing-nothing-in-the-mysql-workbench)

Answer (score 5):

This is still a known, unresolved [issue](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85054) as of MySQL Workbench 6.3.9 build 10690321 CE.

My workaround is to go to `File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script` and then execute the creation script using one of the options under the "Scripting" menu (or in the terminal).

In the [bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=85054), there is also a suggested workaround from Matt Whitney that uses the "Synchronize Model" feature:

> I am having the same issue on Mac OS X 10.11.6. As a *partial*
>   workaround I've been able to use the "Synchronize Model" feature for
>   all of my changes so far on a database that has already been created.
>   Perhaps creating a blank DB and using the Synchronize Model would work
>   for those wanting similar functionality to the "Forward Engineer".

Comment: I dont see a file export option.