# Forward engineer is doing nothing in the MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have little experience with `MySQL Workbench` and need some helps to figure out an issue. I loaded a new EER diagram from a `.MWB` file in the GUI and was trying to convert it into the `SQL` with `Forward engineer`. Initially, I was connected to the `localhost` and when, I press the `Forward engineer...`, nothing happens. The figure is as following, I'm working in the `Mac OS Sierra` operating system.

What I am missing here ? Some advice will help from the more expert users.

[image]

I use `MySQL Workbench 6.3`version for the work,

[image]

Comment: Did you tried on latest version?

Comment: I just installed the workbench and this is I assume is the latest. ]

Comment: Okay, it seems the issue is actually with the latest version of MySQL. I have tried with `version 6.0` and this is actually, working fine. Though, I haven't uninstalled and re-installed the latest version in the machine which might solve it.

Comment: Please fill bug report at bugs.mysql.com, seems you found one.

Comment: I was having this same issue with the latest version and added my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've had this same issue with the latest release of MySQL Workbench (macOS). It's definitely some bug as previously, I didn't have any issues forward engineering.

Here's a workaround:

Normally, you'd go to:

- `Database > Forward Engineer...`

To work around this bug, instead go to:

- `Database > Synchronize Model...`
- This will look for any open ERDs which do not currently exist with the rest of your schemas, and will allow you to forward engineer the schema that way.
- Warning: This could get hairy if you had a lot of ERDs opened and didn't want to synch all of them, so make sure you've got the right ones checked!

I know this is a late answer, but this solution allowed me to forward engineer an ERD which previously was not firing (just as you described, nothing from MySQL Workbench).

I found your post when trying to find a solution, and while troubleshooting, heard via a personal anecdote about this work around. It may already be posted elsewhere on stack (tried to find link but couldn't find it), but hope this helps :)

Comment: This helps me. Installed again the latest version in a new machine and seems the issue still exists.

Comment: It's been a few months since this issue first started appearing and not sure why they haven't resolved it yet...Maybe in the next big update... :/

Comment: Note that you need an existing database in order to use "Synchronize Model"

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
File > Export > Forward Engineer SQL CREATE script
```

Comment: This seems like the same functionality as `Database > Forward Engineer`. Great answer!